# Python read 100+ CSV files and return sum of a column from each CSV file into a new csv

Tags: python, csv

I have 100+ CSV files in the same folder. I'm trying to read all the files which don't have any sequence formatting except all files begin with "AB_". I do not wish to concatenate all these files as these files are originally from a huge file split by ID using Python. I'm trying to verify that all these files are sum up to the right amount.
These files are formatted as below:

```
ID   country   amount

1234   Malaysia    30

1234   Malaysia    80

....
```

All files have different number of rows, and ID column has only 1 distinct ID. I wish to have a CSV file created to summarize all these CSV files by having output as below (each row shows summary from each CSV file from the folder):

```
ID   sum_amount

1234 110

2345 88

...
```

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to read all the files which don't have any sequence formatting except all files begin with "AB_".

[`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) can help you generate this list of files.

Once you have the list of file names, a simple approach to this problem is to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) each file, traverse it line-by-line, and accumulate `sum_amount` by `ID`. You can use a dictionary to store the total `sum_amount` by `ID` up to that point. Once the dictionary's complete (i.e. you've traversed all the files), you'll write that to an output file (you can use dictionary's `items` method to get a list of key-value tuples you can iterate over).

Note this problem doesn't require you to process anything serially: if you could traverse the files in parallel, you could compute file-level totals and then aggregate those partial totals into a grand total for your result set. This is a problem that you could tackle with a map-reduce approach if you needed to tackle it on a recurring basis.